# @media queries being ignored when viewing html emails via iOS Mail

Tags: media-queries, html-email

i am dealing with very strange problem. I have tested on iphone6s and iphone6

1) the email is sent to a non-gmail account that is configured on the iphone

2) the html message is viewed from iOS Mail

3) here is where it gets weird and i will try to describe best as possible
   a) if i view the email directly from the client by click on the email  from the list of emails. The media query is not respected. 
   b) if i view the message, click the down arrow to view the previous message and then click the up to view the original message, the media query is respected.

4) i have tried both icloud and yahoo accounts and two different iphones (6 and 6s)

i have got it down to this simple example. 
of course all the simple emulators work as you would expect and not exhibit the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>this is a test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            /* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */
            /* Portrait */
            @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
                #main-wrapper{
                    max-width: 320px;
                    margin: 2px auto;
                    background-color: red;
                }

            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-wrapper" style=" background-color: #ffffff;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in ante velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas imperdiet erat metus, sed maximus tortor dignissim vel. Fusce luctus eget turpis a pretium. Nunc sagittis vulputate risus et porta. Cras eros nisl, placerat id ultricies sit amet, eleifend vel augue. Nullam dignissim sodales rhoncus. Morbi hendrerit aliquam tortor.

    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla tellus massa, accumsan ac ex a, congue lobortis ipsum. Sed vitae ultrices purus. Nam vulputate lacus vitae massa laoreet scelerisque. Duis in risus non elit sodales pharetra. Nunc ultrices nisl quis leo mollis, sed consectetur tortor placerat. Fusce ultricies eleifend nisi, in congue metus iaculis ut.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by **the default IOS email reader** you mean **iOS Mail**, media queries should be supported. Two things

1. You shouldn't need an `initial-scale` attribute in your viewport tag, have you tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`?
2. Depending on how specific an environment you want this CSS to impact, you might not need such a loaded `@media` tag either. Have you tried something like `@media screen and (max-device-width: 568px)`?

Comment: thanks for the idea
it ended up being the 
and (orientation: portrait) that cause the weirdness